# Is there a way to force the use of the Debian system Ruby Bundler in RVM?

Tags: ruby, debian, rvm, bundler, apt

On Debian GNU/Linux 8 "Jessie" there is a specialized Ruby Bundler which is supposed to be aware of gems that have been installed through Debian's APT system. So in a lot of cases, it shouldn't be necessary to install these gems through rubygems.org again, when they are already installed system-wide.

Now I'm using RVM to install and manage additional Ruby implementations and versions on my systems. RVM seems to set up the environment in a way so that the `bundle` call maps to the executable in the activated Ruby implementation's repository of installed gems.

I am looking for a way to make RVM set up the system-provided, specialized `/usr/bin/bundle` for selected or all Rubies managed by RVM.

Edit:

Some people asked me for the reasons why I would want this. Here they are:

- I like the fact that some additional people that I have quite a bit of trust in (here: the Debian developers responsible for packaging) have a chance to look at the code that ends up being used in my applications.
- Code that is part of a stable distribution of the Debian project is subject to the Debian security team. If some issue comes up, there are additional people dedicated to find a solution quickly.
- As far as I know the usual gem code authentication is dependent on the transport authentication of TLS used at rubygems.com alone. I find the security infrastructure of RubyGems questionable, it has already been compromised by a big hack some years ago, and almost nothing changed since then. I maintained the X.509 based end-to-end authentication system offered by Rubygems for my own software distributions for quite some time and came to the conclusion that this system doesn't perform at all. Only very few gems are ever signed and there is no concept of cryptographic identity exchange.
- I don't like the fact that things that are already present on my system are downloaded and stored again. It seems to be a waste of resources. Even worse when this happens in a less secure way then the original installation.

Comment: I do not think what you want to do makes sense with regards to what RVM brings to the table. RVM creates gem sets for a given Ruby version, so that an install is "self-contained" and consistent. So you can use the system Bundler for the system Ruby version, but not the others. And so, if you use RVM to install another version, it will install Bundler built for that new version---ultimately a different version than the system one.

Comment: For me, gemsets are a feature that has become irrelevant since Bundler exists, because it is essentially able to do the same thing in a more spontaneous and flexible way. I primarily use RVM to install and maintain additional Ruby implementations and I don't see how it wouldn't make sense to reuse some preinstalled Ruby libraries when using RVM.

Comment: I think this is historical. Bundler is built *on top* of Ruby and Rubygems. It means that it depends on them and its execution may change depending on how they were set. It can still happen today (I'd like to be outdated here) that Bundler succeeds to install a gem on some version of Ruby, and not another. RVM is orthogonal to Bundler, in that its goal is to setup a "closed" and "well-defined" and "turn-key" Ruby environment. Bundler works on top of such an environment, and no guarantee outside. Note that this is improving a lot, I think since Ruby 2.0, so you may be lucky.